# Setting a default todo list in KOrganizer

Tags: kde, configuration, calendar

I've been using KOrganizer's calendar for awhile now, synching it with my Android phone's calendar using Google's calendar. Now I want to start using the todo list. Synching it with my phone using Google tasks was easy(cause I've already done most of the work when I did it for the calendar), and I can create tasks via my computer and check them via my phone.

Now, the input line at the bottom of the todo list in KOrganizer is supposed to allow me to easily type tasks for my todo list, but when I type the task and press Enter, KOrganizer opens a dialog, prompting me to choose between my Google tasks list and the local todo list.

Is there a way to disable this dialog, sending all new tasks created via this input line to Google tasks by default?